# Find a file with specific extension and use as a parameter in command line

Tags: batch-file

I have a question. 
I need a script (for .bat file) to find a file with an .appx extension in current folder and use it as a parameter in script `add-appxpackage {Path to this file}`

This is for Windows 8 package installation (for testing needs). Just for quick updating new version of a programm in a testing environment.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: there wasn't a question there, you essentially said "give me teh codez".  What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a batch file, use the `for` statement to run a command for each file in a directory.

```
@for %%a in (*.appx) do ( add-appxpackage "%%~fa" )
```

For more info, type `help for` at the command line.

Comment: it works but if I add "powershell" in batch, like this: 

@for %%a in (*.appx) do ( powershell add-appxpackage "%%~fa" )